# Equivalente a SOMASES do Excel, no R

Tags: r

Estou me aprofundando no R e procuro uma função que seja equivalente ao somases do excel.

Tenho este seguinte DF:

```
Day.of.Week Hour    Quantidade
5            21         5044
3            12         5024
1            11         4725
0            16         4643
1            15         4601
4            14         4566
2            20         4509
1            10         4502
3            13         4477
6            11         4449
```

Eu preciso que ele faça o equivalente ao `Somases` para montar algo do tipo

```
Hour 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
1    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
2    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
3    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
4    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
5    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
6    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
7    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
8    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
9    -  -  -  -  -  -  -
10   -  -  -  -  -  -  -
...
```

Ele somaria a quantidade conforme o dia da semana e a hora.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito de várias formas, como pode ser visto pelas várias respostas. Uma maneira sem usar pacotes adicionar é usar `tapply`:

```
> tapply(df$Quantidade, list(df$Day.of.Week, df$Hour), sum)
    10   11   12   13   14   15   16   20   21
0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 4643   NA   NA
1 4502 4725   NA   NA   NA 4601   NA   NA   NA
2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 4509   NA
3   NA   NA 5024 4477   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4   NA   NA   NA   NA 4566   NA   NA   NA   NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 5044
6   NA 4449   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

O que fica como linhas ou colunas depende da ordem da lista passada como segundo argumento. Se a ordem for invertida, o resultado é transposto:

```
> tapply(df$Quantidade, list(df$Hour, df$Day.of.Week), sum)
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6
10   NA 4502   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
11   NA 4725   NA   NA   NA   NA 4449
12   NA   NA   NA 5024   NA   NA   NA
13   NA   NA   NA 4477   NA   NA   NA
14   NA   NA   NA   NA 4566   NA   NA
15   NA 4601   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
16 4643   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
20   NA   NA 4509   NA   NA   NA   NA
21   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 5044   NA
```

Comment: Código bem elegante.

Comment: Cara sensacional, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar duas funções do R: `aggregate` para somar as "duplicadas", de forma a você ter apenas um caso de dia/hora para cada quantidade e a função `acast` da biblioteca `reshape2` para criar a matriz do jeito que você esta pedindo.

#### Sua data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Day.of.Week = c(5,3,1,0,1,4,2,1,3,6), 
                 Hour = c(21,12,11,16,15,14,20,10,13,11), 
                 Quantidade = c(5044,5024,4725,4643,4601,4566,4509,4502,4477,4449))
```

#### Código:

```
require(reshape2)

df <- aggregate(Quantidade ~ ., df, sum)
somases <- acast(df, Hour ~ Day.of.Week, value.var = "Quantidade")
```

#### Output:

```
> somases
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6
10   NA 4502   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
11   NA 4725   NA   NA   NA   NA 4449
12   NA   NA   NA 5024   NA   NA   NA
13   NA   NA   NA 4477   NA   NA   NA
14   NA   NA   NA   NA 4566   NA   NA
15   NA 4601   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
16 4643   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
20   NA   NA 4509   NA   NA   NA   NA
21   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 5044   NA
```

No caso os NA's representam casos aonde não existe nenhum valor.

[Uma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346316/how-to-apply-function-over-columns-of-matrix-by-multiple-factors-in-r) relacionada em inglês.

Comment: Acho que o `aggregate` não é necessário neste seu código, ele só muda a ordem das linhas do data frame e reseta os row names.

Comment: Realmente ele não é necessário para esse caso, mas caso tenha mais de uma ocorrência no mesmo dia e hora o `acast` não funcionaria sem o aggregate.

Comment: Ah sim, faz sentido. É que eu na verdade nunca usei `acast`, não tinha parado para observar o que a função faz.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 5):

A maneira que eu mais gosto é a seguinte, usando os pacotes `dplyr`e `tidyr` que são especializados para transformações em `data.frames`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(Day.of.Week, Hour) %>%
  summarise(Quantidade = sum(Quantidade)) %>%
  spread(Day.of.Week, Quantidade, fill = 0)

Source: local data frame [9 x 8]

   Hour     0     1     2     3     4     5     6
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1    10     0  4502     0     0     0     0     0
2    11     0  4725     0     0     0     0  4449
3    12     0     0     0  5024     0     0     0
4    13     0     0     0  4477     0     0     0
5    14     0     0     0     0  4566     0     0
6    15     0  4601     0     0     0     0     0
7    16  4643     0     0     0     0     0     0
8    20     0     0  4509     0     0     0     0
9    21     0     0     0     0     0  5044     0
```

Se você não possuir os pacotes instalados precisará usar: `install.packages(c("dplyr", "tidyr"))` para instalar.

Para mim as vantagens de se fazer assim são:

- o resultado continua sendo um `data.frame`. Nas respostas do @Molx e do @André Mutao resultado é uma matriz sem nome das dimensões..
- não é necessário explicitar uma linha para cada dia da semana. Na resposta do @carlosfigueira é necessário fazer "hard code" dos dias da semana.
- é possível utilizar o argumento `fill` da função `spread` para preencher automaticamente as caselas vazias com algum valor. no caso, acredito que não deva ser `NA` e sim `0`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar uma biblioteca de manipulação de valores como o `dplyr` para somar as quantidades baseado em dia da semana / hora, e depois manipular o resultado para obter o formato que você quer. O código abaixo mostra um exemplo de como isso pode ser feito.

```
dow <- sample(0:6, 1000, replace = TRUE)
h <- sample(0:23, 1000, replace = TRUE)
q <- floor(runif(1000, 100, 10000))
df <- data.frame(Day.of.Week = dow, Hour = h, Quantidade = q)

library(dplyr)
somas <- df %>%
    group_by(Day.of.Week, Hour) %>%
    summarize(soma = sum(Quantidade))

perDay <- split(somas, somas$Day.of.Week)
result <- data.frame(Hour = perDay[[1]]$Hour,
                     Su = perDay[[1]]$soma,
                     Mo = perDay[[2]]$soma,
                     Tu = perDay[[3]]$soma,
                     We = perDay[[4]]$soma,
                     Th = perDay[[5]]$soma,
                     Fr = perDay[[6]]$soma,
                     Sa = perDay[[7]]$soma)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!!